# Creating Xcode Projects with Projucer - Source Control Doesn’t Show Modified Files

Tags: xcode, macos, version-control, juce

[I asked this on the JUCE forums and haven't found a definitive answer yet](https://forum.juce.com/t/creating-xcode-projects-with-projucer-source-control-doesnt-show-modified-files/20398), other than at least one other user ISN'T having this issue, but I have no idea what his OS, Xcode, or JUCE version combination is.

Here's my issue:

If I create a project in Xcode and use source control, after a commit, any modifications to files causes the normal "M" to appear next to the source file.

If I create a project with the Projucer, say a GUI application, then use source control in Xcode, modifications to files don't cause the files to show the "M" in front of them. They act as if they haven't been modified.

Anyone with similar experience? Any fixes?

Mac OS 10.12.2
Xcode 8.2
JUCE Grapefruit (4.3.0 - I believe)

Before making any modifications
[image]

After making a simple change and saving the project (which normally causes the "M" to appear)
[image]

Also, making a first commit, then changing a bunch of text in different files, saving them, and running "discard all changes" in the source control menu does NOTHING. I'm pretty familiar with source control in Xcode and have never had trouble with it until I created an app with the Projucer.  However, Version control IS WORKING for *.xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I was placing the git folder in the incorrect location.  The Projucer makes its own folder hierarchy and places the source files in a different location than Xcode does, so I needed to make sure Xcode could see these files by putting the git folder outside of the directory of the source files.